# Java: selecting objects, that have been repainted

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am a student and having trubble making one of my projects this is only one bit of what my final project will actual be like but i am trying to compartmentalize it as much as possible.

the specific problem I have is related to creating a java application that displays a frame with a button allowing the user to create multiple  balls on  screen and then have you be able to select each one by clicking on them.

I have tryed to add small modifications but with non of them working i removed it so that it gives you more freedom when finding a solution.

Here is the code of `Simulation` class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Simulation {

   int noOfBallClicks = 0;

   Simulation() {
      buildTheGUI();
   }
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
   JPanel panal = new JPanel();
   JButton add = new JButton("add a new object");

   public void buildTheGUI() {
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(500, 500);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(panal);
      panal.add(add);
      add.addActionListener(new ButtonClickHandler());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Simulation();
   }

   class ButtonClickHandler implements ActionListener {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         noOfBallClicks = noOfBallClicks++;
         frame.add(new Ball());
         frame.validate();
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code of `Ball` class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ball extends JPanel {

   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int w;
   private int h;

   Ball() {
      this.x = 200;
      this.y = 200;
      this.w = 100;
      this.h = 100;
   }

   Ball(int a) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      this.w = 100;
      this.h = 100;
      this.x = rand.nextInt(300);
      this.y = rand.nextInt(300);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(x, y, h, w);
   }
}
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript. This code is Java. Not JavaScript.

Comment: What's your question? Are we supposed to try running this program, guess what doesn't work, and provide you the fixed code?

Comment: so sorry, want to know how to make it have multiple balls on screen and be able select them, should be this in the section                  `class ButtonClickHandler implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 frame.add(new Ball(1));
frame.validate();
 }
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the specific problem I have is related to creating a java application
>   that displays a frame with a button allowing the user to create
>   multiple balls on screen and then have you be able to select each one
>   by clicking on them.
>
> I have tryed to add small modifications but with non of them working i
>   removed it so that it gives you more freedom when finding a solution.

You never mention what is wrong/what you want to achieve... Besides the above and title: *selecting objects, that have been repainted*

However I see a few problems in the code given:

1) Dont set `JFrame` visible until all components have been added (or you will have problems such as content not being visible)

2) Dont call `setSize` on `JFrame` rather override `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` and return `Dimension`s which fit the drawings on `Graphics` object and/or use an appropriate `LayoutManager`. Than we can call `pack()` instead of `setSize(...)` on `JFrame`.

3) Swing components should be created and manipulated on *Event Dispatch Thread* via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)` block. [Read Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more.

4) When you use `validate()` it should be followed by a call to `repaint()` to reflect changes made.

5) You are also using a default `JFrame` Layout of `BorderLayout` to which you add a panel, and than balls (using the button listener) by default `BorderLayout` will add to its `BorderLayout.CENTER` so on each call to `JFrame#add(Component c)` you are replacing the old *ball*/`JPanel` with another.

6) As it stands using `JPanel` like you have if 2 `Ball`s end up in an overlapping position the top `Ball` and its `JPanel` will cover the bottom `Ball`... You need a transparent panel i.e `JComponent#setOpaque(false)`.

7) When I do *custom painting*, I rarely use `JComponent` or its extensions. I rather create an `Object` which will act as *virtual representation* of what I need to be drawn/displayed or whatever (maybe personal preference). These objects will than be visualized in my `JPanel` `paintComponent(..)` which will call their `draw(..)` method passing the `Graphics` object of the `JPanel` to each `Ball` which will than draw itself according to the the fields data.

Here is a short example I made (with the above in mind):

All green `balls` have been selected i.e clicked on, while the red has not.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

        drawPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseClicked(me);
                for (Ball b : drawPanel.getBalls()) {//iterate through each ball
                    if (b.getBounds().contains(me.getPoint())) {//get the ball bounds and check if mouse click was within its bounds
                        if (!b.isSelected()) {//check if ball has been clicked on
                            b.setSelected(true);
                        } else {
                            b.setSelected(false);
                        }
                        drawPanel.repaint();//so ball color change will be shown
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton createBallButton = new JButton("Add ball");
        createBallButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            private int counter = 1;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int ballRadius = 10;
                int x = rand.nextInt(drawPanel.getWidth());
                int y = rand.nextInt(drawPanel.getHeight());

                //check that we dont go offscreen by subtarcting its radius unless its x and y are not bigger than radius
                if (y > ballRadius) {
                    y -= ballRadius;
                }
                if (x > ballRadius) {
                    x -= ballRadius;
                }

                drawPanel.addBall(new Ball(x, y, ballRadius, counter));//add ball to panel to be drawn
                counter++;//increase the ball number
            }
        });

        final JTextArea jtf = new JTextArea(5, 10);
        jtf.setEditable(false);
        JButton printSelectedBallButton = new JButton("Print selected balls");
        printSelectedBallButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            private int counter = 1;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtf.setText("");
                for (Ball b : drawPanel.getBalls()) {
                    if (b.isSelected()) {
                        jtf.append("Selected: " + b.getNumber() + "\n");
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        controlPanel.add(createBallButton);
        controlPanel.add(printSelectedBallButton);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtf);
        controlPanel.add(jsp);

        frame.add(drawPanel);
        frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addBall(Ball b) {
        balls.add(b);
        repaint();
    }

    public ArrayList<Ball> getBalls() {
        return balls;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            ball.draw(g2d);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}

class Ball {

    private Color color;
    private int x, y;
    private int radius;
    private final int number;
    private boolean selected;

    Ball(int x, int y, int radius, int counter) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.number = counter;
        selected = false;
        this.color = Color.RED;//default color of unselected ball
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        Color prevColor = g2d.getColor();
        g2d.drawString(number + "", x + radius, y + radius);//draw the number of ball
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);
        g2d.setColor(prevColor);
    }

    public Rectangle2D getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, radius, radius);
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
        if (selected) {
            color = Color.GREEN;
        } else {
            color = Color.RED;
        }
    }

    boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry not great at explaining myself, i'll try harder next time